# Очищение слоя маркеров JavaScript API Яндекс Карт 3.0 или удаление всех маркеров перед добавлением новых

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

В моём приложении есть Vue-компонент для карты, реализованной с помощью JavaScript API Яндекс Карт 3.0. Я не использую Vuefy module.

В компонент карты я передаю массив объектов с координатами и расставляю по этим координатам маркеры. Добавляю маркеры на карту таким образом:

```typescript
markersProps.forEach((el) => {
  const marker = new ymaps3.YMapMarker(
    {
      coordinates: el.coordinates,
      properties: el.properties,
    },
    markerElement,
  )
  map.addChild(marker)
})
```

Когда массив markersProps меняется, я хочу удалить с карты все имеющиеся маркеры (или очистить слой карты, на который помещаются маркеры) и рисовать новые маркеры заново.

```typescript
watch(
  () => props.markerData,
  (newMarkers, oldMarkers) => {
    // здесь нужно очистить слой маркеров или удалить имеющиеся маркеры
    addMarkers(newMarkers)
  },
  { deep: true },
)
```

Я пробовал хранить добавленные на карту маркеры в отдельной переменной `const addedMarkers = ref<YMapMarker[]>([])` и передавать их в `map.removeChild(marker)`, но это не сработало (removeChild метод ожидает аргумент типа `YMapEntity<unknown, {}>`, а я пытаюсь передавать ему `YMapMarker`).

Так же я не нашёл в документации методов очищения дефолтных или кастомных слоёв.

Как я могу реализовать описанный функционал обновления маркеров на карте?

Comment: Может быть вам подойдёт размещение меток в коллекции? 
var Coll = new YMapCollection(); map.addChild(Coll) 
Тогда можно удалять коллекцию с карты, создавать её заново, добавлять на карту повторно и наполнять содержимым уже очищенную. 
map.removeChild(Coll); 
Coll = new YMapCollection(); 
map.addChild(Coll);